# PL/SQL Trigger issues (copy data from table 1 to table 2)

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

i have looked around and tried a couple of solutions i have read. i am trying to create a pl/sql trigger that will copy data from one table to another if a clause is met. i feel i may just be making a silly syntax error rather then a full critical failure but would appreciate some help.

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_APPLICATIONS
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE OF APP_ID, Status_id
ON APPLICATIONS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

:new.APP_ID := SEQ_APP_ID.nextval;
:new.APP_DATE := SYSDATE;

IF STATUS_ID = 2 OR STATUS_ID = 5 OR STATUS_ID = 7 OR STATUS_ID = 8 THEN
INSERT INTO APP_HISTORY
SELECT SRN, STATUS_ID, APP_DATE
FROM APPLICATIONS;
END IF;

END;
```

here are the errors

> 6  4   PLS-00201: identifier 'STATUS_ID' must be declared
>
> 6  1   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: do you have any error? or your triggers isnt working?

Comment: looks like we are just guessing. Because beside the syntaxis errors ( the miss of :new and the wrong insert) we dont know what your query should be doing.

Comment: Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
   And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you note that you need to reference the values with :NEW to get the current value of STATUS of ID for this insert or update, you will then hit your second error - you can't query the table on which the trigger exists as its content is in flux. You will get a mutating table error. Not to mention that you had no where clause on the SELECT so you would be dumping all of APPLICATIONS into APP_HISTORY. I'm betting that all you want is to copy over the row as it was before the update. Of course there was no row before the insert, so there would be nothing to copy over. Or do you want to copy the NEW values into the HISTORY table on insert?

Assuming that you want to keep the old values on update, then you would:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_APPLICATIONS
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE OF APP_ID, Status_id
ON APPLICATIONS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

-- APP_ID better not be the PK or it is changing on UPDATE! 
-- IF you only want this value set once on INSERT, wrap it in an IF INSERTING ... END IF; structure
:new.APP_ID := SEQ_APP_ID.nextval;
:new.APP_DATE := SYSDATE;

IF UPDATING AND ( :NEW.STATUS_ID = 2 OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 5 OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 7 OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 8 )
THEN
   INSERT INTO APP_HISTORY (SRN, STATUS_ID, APP_DATE)
   VALUES (:OLD.SRN, :OLD.STATUS_ID, :OLD.APP_DATE);
END IF;

END;
```

Other thoughts on your first cut of the trigger - your trigger fires on update of app_id, but then changes the app_id again inside the trigger. So if your UI is setting an APP_ID value and then using that value to insert dependent records - you've just messed that up.

Comment: Why only `updating` ? triggers is for update and insert

Comment: Normally history tables don't also include the current row, which is why I asked his/her intent and explained my assumptions for my answer before copying the :OLD values into the history table. I also explained mutating tables, and I'd also question why the APP_ID is getting changed on update. I sure hope that it isn't the PK! Anyway, just giving as much info as I can to an obvious beginner.

Comment: In fact, if you look at the trigger declaration, it fires on update of app_id and then will change the app_id AGAIN inside the trigger. Ouch! There is so much wrong with the first cut that person needs to pause, take a breath, and get a clearer definition of what they want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting another issue with my code, between me and my work mates we never thought of the fact it would change the primary key each update ill revise all my triggers to fix this problem. thank you Michael for both helping me fix an if statement and major issue.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need add `NEW`

```
IF :NEW.STATUS_ID = 2 OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 5 
OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 7 OR :NEW.STATUS_ID = 8 THEN
    INSERT INTO APP_HISTORY (srn, status_id, app_date)
    VALUES (:NEW.SRN, :NEW.STATUS_ID, :NEW.APP_DATE);
END IF;
```

Comment: Don't forget the colon - :NEW not NEW

Comment: IF NEW.STATUS_ID = 2 OR NEW.STATUS_ID = 5 OR NEW.STATUS_ID = 7 OR NEW.STATUS_ID = 8 THEN

Produces this error 

Compilation failed, line 6 (14:08:58) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.STATUS_ID' must be declaredCompilation failed, line 6 (14:08:58) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: IF :new.STATUS_ID = 2 OR :new.STATUS_ID = 5 OR :new.STATUS_ID = 7 OR :new.STATUS_ID = 8 THEN

Produces this error

PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough valuesCompilation failed, line 7 (14:07:38) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


if i fix the thing to :new.

Comment: can you describe your `app_history` table? I make an update to include the field name to insert.

Comment: just holds the values history_id (auto generated via trigger), srn, app_date and status_id

Comment: @MichaelBroughton You are right for a moment I tought was MySQL instead of Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRG_APPLICATIONS
  BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE OF APP_ID, Status_id
  ON APPLICATIONS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

  :new.APP_ID := SEQ_APP_ID.nextval;
  :new.APP_DATE := SYSDATE;

  IF :new.STATUS_ID = 2 OR 
     :new.STATUS_ID = 5 OR 
     :new.STATUS_ID = 7 OR 
     :new.STATUS_ID = 8 THEN

    INSERT INTO APP_HISTORY (srn, status_id, app_date)
     values (:new.srn, :new.status_id, :new.app_date);

 END IF;

END;
```

Comment: Compilation failed, line 11 (14:11:22) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough valuesCompilation failed, line 11 (14:11:22) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: so maybe you should name the columns at your insert statement e.g. insert into app_history(column1, column2, column3) values (:new.srn, :new.status_id, :new.app_date)

Comment: what is the structure of your "APP_HISTORY" table?

Comment: @PT_STAR OP describe the table in a comment in my answer

Comment: and by the way, if you want to store the old values, you can use the :OLD prefix (just in case of update).... if updating then ...